# Get relative information about phone movement inside of a car - Android

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am wondering if there is any way that I can make an app that detects moment of the phone inside of a moving car. Let me expand. Lets say I want to make an app that displays the phones relative speed, or velocity. If the phone is not moving inside of the car, but the car is moving 50 mph...I do not want the app to display 50 mph. I want the app to display 0mph. But if the phone is thrown in the moving car... I want the app to only display the speed at which the phone was thrown.

Please let me know if this is possible and how I should go about this :) Thank  you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to get very accurate data for this.  Accelerometers are very noisy, and the signal you're looking for is small compared to the signal of the car itself accelerating and adecelerating.  GPS isn't really accurate enough for small movements within a car.

What you really need is a second source of data for the car alone.  Either hooking into the car's data via an SDK (I think Ford and some others have this) or from a second phone that stays stationary in the device.  These two devices could be calibrated together, and then the delta between the two devices would be the phone's movement relative to the car.  Expect it to be extremely noisy though-  accelerometers in phones are noisy and sensitive.  And over time random noise would make it less accurate until you recalibrate.